# 2013 Accord HDD gone after factory reset

Tags: honda, audio, accord

I performed a factory reset on my 2013 Accord EXL but now there is no HDD available. I have am/fm/cd/xm, but no HDD.  Is there a way to recover this without a trip to the dealer?

Answer (score 0):

factory reset your audio? or what?
could you please elaborate?

if the the audio docks you can try to search what kind audio brand you are using.. 
example : JVC
and the type example : TF67B

than you can look it up to google, check if there is a firmware update and how to update the firmware to open HDD.